# Why does my SARIMA model not capture the seasonality?

Tags: arima, autoregressive, seasonality

I have sales data over 100+ days. Every Saturday has 0 sales. For the other days there is also a clear seasonality. Tuesday always has the highest sales, and the order in which the other days follow are the same in 9/10 of the cases.

However when I model an auto_arima, with seasonality = True and m = 7 (weekly), my model often predicts negative values or sometimes even very high values for these Saturdays, whilst from the examples this never can be 'learned'. Am I doing something wrong, or understanding something wrong here?

Comment: It sounds as if you want your model to be able to mimic big falls from Friday to Saturday and also never to turn negative. You should wonder whether that is possible with the functional form and number of parameters you are fitting. If the process shuts down on Saturdays, omit them from the data; your time variable could then be modified to count over the other days. What about Sundays?

Comment: Yes, in fact there is just no data for Saturday. After talking to the firms manager, they said it is the same as 0 sales. I added the Saturdays and 0 sales because I expected my model to work better. What you suggest is to just omit this and then fill in 0 my self?

So for example it's Monday, it predicts 6 steps ahead. This would then be Tuesday (1), Wednesday (2), Thursday (3), Friday (4), Saturday (fill in 0 my self), Sunday (5), Monday (6)?

Comment: That sounds right. There is nothing to predict for Saturdays.